# PHP array_diff output

Tags: php, array-difference

I am using array_diff correctly to compare 2 arrays.

In documentation, it says the output is like this:

```
Array
(
   [1] => blue
)
```

As you can see, each output will come in a single line.

But when I try it, it only shows me output in 1 line.

[image]

Maybe now can be a little friendly, because I only have 4 rows to compare, but I'm supposed to have, in the future, hundreds of them.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Just use `echo "<pre>"` before `print_r`. It is pre-formatted text

Comment: use pre tag.... or code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "pretty print" your array:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

the "pre" is used to print pretty arrays

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($array);
print "</pre>";
```

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use print or echo and print `<pre>` and `</pre>` while array printing:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
print "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Both results are same, the first result is printed using `<pre>` tag with `print_r($array)`.

So you can get the output like second result using,

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));
    echo "</pre>";
```

[print_f](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [arraydiff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)